# git fetch --all - extra branches being created

Tags: git, git-branch, git-fetch

I've got my USB stick set up as a git repo (don't ask why) but I just did a `git fetch --all` and got these messages:

```
   38ea2b1..2b4fdaf  master     -> usb/master
 * [new branch]      usb/branch/A -> usb/usb/branch/A
 * [new branch]      usb/branch/B -> usb/usb/branch/B
 * [new branch]      usb/master -> usb/usb/master
```

which looks worrying.

It appears there are additional branches being created that aren't necessary. Is this going to be the start of an infinite loop of `usb/usb/usb/usb` branches?

What should I do to squash this and avoid the problem?

==== UPDATE 1

In `.git/config` I have:

```
[remote "usb"]
        url = /path/to/usb/repo.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/usb/*
```

which looks pretty standard. But then directly below it I've got this weird stuff:

```
[branch "branch/A"]
        remote = usb
        merge = refs/heads/branch/A
[branch "usb/branch/B"]
        remote = .
        merge = refs/heads/branch/A
[branch "usb/branch/C"]
        remote = .
        merge = refs/heads/branch/A
```

This continues. Around 20 entries in total.

What's going on here?

==== UPDATE 2

My USB project.git/config contains:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = C:/xampp/htdocs/networkroot/.
```

Not sure if that's as it should be.

Comment: What's in your `${HOME}/.gitconfig` and your repository `.git/config` files? I suspect this is a badly written fetch refspec...

Comment: Anything specific? There are 122 lines in total.

Comment: The `[remote "origin"]` section (assuming your remote is actually named "origin") would be sufficient...

Comment: Do you have `usb` remote in the USB repo?

Comment: @StenSoft No. I'm pasting my project.git/config in my question.

Comment: I do not fully understand: Do you have one repository on the USB drive and one on the local hard drive? Where do you try to `fetch`? The config of "Update 1" is from the repository on the hard drive and the config of "Update 2" is from the repository on the USB drive?